# How do I save a non-trivial value to an attribute in Elixir?

Tags: elixir

So I understand that when defining attributes for a module in Elixir the syntax is `@myvariable 30` however, in my case let's say my module is defined as follows:

```
defmodule MyModule do
   def add(x,y), do: x + y
   @myvariable add(3,4)
   def print, do: @myvariable
end
```

Ideally this should print out 7, however I get a `CompileError: undefined function add/2`

In my specific case, the value that I want to store as an attribute is a somewhat large map so not as trivial as `add(3,4)` but I'm pretty sure that the same concept applies. If attributes are not the correct way to go about this, please let me know what the real "elixir" way to go about it is.

In my case, **I want to be able to access certain keys of my map throughout my module** instead of having to pass the whole map as a parameter to each function.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@values` are not variables, they are [**Module Attributes**](http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/module-attributes.html). They are not stored in the module by default and the value exists only during compile-time. From the Elixir ['Getting Started' Guide](http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/module-attributes.html):

> **Module attributes in Elixir serve three purposes:**
>
> 1. They serve to annotate the module, often with information to be used by the user or the VM.
> 2. They work as constants.
> 3. They work as a temporary module storage to be used during compilation.

---

The problem with your code is that `@myvariable` is being set during the compilation of `MyModule` but `add(3, 4)` can't be calculated since the module hasn't been compiled yet.

The simplest solution is to define `add(x, y)` in another module and call it from there:

```
defmodule OtherModule do
  def add(x, y), do: x + y
end

defmodule MyModule do
  @myvariable OtherModule.add(3, 4)
  def print, do: @myvariable
end
```

---

You can [similarly define your `Map` as a Module attribute](https://github.com/sheharyarn/explay/blob/master/lib/explay/request/base.ex#L53-L82), but after compilation it will become a constant so you won't be able to modify it (which I guess is what you want).